# Re-install MacOS with bootable USB

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, disk-format, activation-lock

I'm trying to reinstall MacOS Catalina on a second hand Macbook Pro 2019.
I cannot access Disk Utils in any way specified on the web. Only option that is available is Internet Recovery and I face an "Activation Lock" window that I cannot seem to bypass whatsoever.

In Internet Recovery window I have the following options: shutdown, restart, activate using MDM key and Erase Mac.
The last option is: Startup disk that won't allow me to boot on my USB. It gives the following error:

> security settings does not allow this mac to use an external startup disk<

How can I format and reinstall this Mac? I do not know the Apple-ID used for this Mac and neither does the previous owner.

Comment: Then I would suspect the previous 'owner' was not actually the owner - caveat emptor. Unlocking a T2 Mac is not a trivial task. Apple will do it for you if you take it to an Apple Store with proof of ownership. Otherwise you own a brick.

Comment: What @Tetsujin said.  The fact you see MDM indicates this might of been owned by an organization meaning if they don’t know the AppleID, they weren’t the owners

Comment: Truth is this Mac was bought by our company and given out to one of our customer. And one of their employees has used her Apple-ID to register this Mac. Now I've been assigned to format and reinstall but it seems to be a very tricky task indeed.

Comment: Not something I've ever needed to do myself, so idk details, but this is what your MDM is for.